# caret::groupKFold and validation/testing

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

This is unknown territory, so please let me know if the question is not clear.

I'm trying to fit a random forest with caret. I have a dataset of about 160 observations where 60/160 are repeated measures so I need to make sure the same ids(patients) are not used for training and validation. Because of this I've used groupKFold to create 5 folds before training the model.

What I can't understand is at which point do I use/select data for actual testing/validation AFTER training the model? In other words, where is the "newdata"? `predict(rf_mod, "??")`

```
folds <- groupKFold(rf_data$id, k = 5)

rf_data <- rf_data %>% select(-id)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 5,
                           index = folds,
                           search = "random")

rf_mod <- train(cancer ~ ., rf_data,
                method = "rf",
                trControl = fitControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is good practice to write a code that is reproducible. We are not sitting on the same data as you are...

However, this question is rather straight forward. I recommend you to have a look on the documentation, `?groupKFold`. Where you can see: "A series of test/training partitions are created using `createDataPartition`" and "`groupKFold` splits the data based on a grouping factor".

In the code you present you split the data in to the different cross validation folds, but then you use **all** your data in the training. By using `createDataPartition` **before** using `groupKFold`, you can e.g. hold out 70% of your data by:

```
set.seed(10)
train_ind <- createDataPartition(rf_data$cancer, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
train_dat <- rf_data[train_ind,]
test_dat <- rf_data[!train_ind,]
```

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation suggests that OP is doing this correct with the use of the `index` argument: https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#simple-splitting-with-important-groups

Comment: Yes I'm sure. OP:s goal is to have a dataset to test the trained model, then you better save some data after the train. They you  want to hold out some of the data, and `createDataPartition` is a good way of doing so.