# randomForest Package cross validation with repeated measures?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, r-caret

I have made a nice random forest model with the randomForest package. But!! My data is repeated measures, so I need to make sure the same individuals are not used in the training and testing data. I would like to run what is equivalent to this thread in the randomForest package: [caret::groupKFold and validation/testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868902/caretgroupkfold-and-validation-testing).

Is this possible or do I need to use the Caret package and redo the model for this?

I know you can run cross validation in the randomForest package using the rfcv function, but this doesn't seem to account for grouping factors?

Or should I somehow use the data splitting in caret and then feed this into the randomForest package model?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve repeated measures cross-validation and ensure that the same individuals are not used in both the training and testing data with the caret package. caret::groupKFold is a useful function in this context. You can combine caret and randomForest to perform repeated measures cross-validation. I would:

1. Use groupKFold from caret to create the cross-validation folds while taking into account the grouping factor.
2. Fit the randomForest model using the training data from each fold.
3. Evaluate the model on the corresponding test data from each fold.
4. Repeat the process for all folds and calculate the performance metrics.

Hope that helps